# Creating new column in R dataframe by selecting and matching

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
    item = c("Box 1", "Tape", "Pen"), 
    length = c(2, 10, NA),
    width = c(4, 3, NA), 
    height  = c(6, NA, NA),
    color = c(NA, "clear", "red"),
    option_1 = c("length", "width", "color"),
    option_2 = c("width", "length", NA),
    option_3 = c("height", "color", NA)
    )
```

```
   item length width height color option_1 option_2 option_3
1 Box 1      2     4      6  <NA>   length    width   height
2  Tape     10     3     NA clear    width   length    color
3   Pen     NA    NA     NA   red    color     <NA>     <NA>
```

I want to use the option columns 1,2,3 to pull the appropriate values from length, weight, height. For example, Tape's option_2 is length so it will match to 10 sort of like index matching in Excel.

Ulimately I want this calculated column (option_set) attached to the end of the original dataframe. A tidyverse solution would be appreciated. I was thinking doing select and unite but got stuck.

```
   item length width height color option_1 option_2 option_3                   option_set
1 Box 1      2     4      6  <NA>   length    width   height               size:2 x 4 x 6
2  Tape     10     3     NA clear    width   length    color    size:3 x 10, color: clear 
3   Pen     NA    NA     NA   red    color     <NA>     <NA>                   color: red
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple version of this could be done with a join between a longer version of the data and a longer version of the options you want:

###### Data prep

```
# function to make all character data in longer shape
lengthen <- function(df){
  df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
    pivot_longer(-item) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value))
}

df_data <- select(df, !starts_with("option")) %>% lengthen
df_options <- select(df, item, starts_with("option")) %>% lengthen
```

###### Join df_options with df_data, summarize, and add to df

```
bind_cols(
  df,
  df_options %>%
    transmute(item, name = value) %>%
    left_join(df_data) %>%
    group_by(item) %>%
    summarize(option_set = paste(value, collapse = ",")) %>%
    select(-item))
```

Result

```
Joining, by = c("item", "name")
   item length width height color option_1 option_2 option_3 option_set
1 Box 1      2     4      6  <NA>   length    width   height      2,4,6
2  Tape     10     3     NA clear    width   length    color        red
3   Pen     NA    NA     NA   red    color     <NA>     <NA> 3,10,clear
```

What's a little trickier is you have some implied metadata that puts `length / width / height` into a `size` group. That will take a little more thought to implement.